# How to test async django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, async-await, uvicorn

I have a problem with testing async mode in the django rest framework using the [adrf](https://github.com/em1208/adrf) library.
I created a django project with the view:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view as sync_api_view

@sync_api_view(['GET'])
def my_not_async_view(request):
    print('before block endpoint')
    time.sleep(15)
    return Response({"message": "my_async_view"})
```

and I run this code with the uvicorn: `uvicorn async_django.asgi:application --workers=1` and test with the curl

```
for x in `seq 1 3`; do time curl http://localhost:8000/async-test/not-async & done; echo Starting
```

And I expect console log result to be (#1):

```
before block endpoint
and after 15 sec another
before block endpoint
```

but actual result is (#2):

```
before block endpoint
before block endpoint # runs in another thread
before block endpoint # runs in another thread
```

Why I want result to be (#1) ? Because I want to test async mode and be sure that async mode handling my request, not a thread/instance of the project:

```
import asyncio
from adrf.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET'])
async def get_async_response(request):
    print("async code is running")

    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    return Response({"message": "async_result"})
```

So my logic is when I send a request to `my_not_async_view` I shouldn't see `before block endpoint` after 1 call until it gives a response, because it should block my project, but when I send a request to `get_async_response`, I should be able to see `async code is running` as many times as I send a request ...